Is there any difference between using "while" with the present simple versus using "while" with the present continuous?

I am dancing while she sings.

While I am dancing she sings.


Is there any difference between them? I think both are almost the same and that the actions in both happen at the same time, right?

Yes, they mean the same. Both actions are happening at the same time. The activities are usually independent, as in your two examples, although not necessarily "She sings while I accompany her on the piano".
While does have other meanings, see here and here for the Cambridge and Merriam Webster Dictionaries' definitions.

Jenings so, it is like saying " While I am dancing she is singing" all three with the same meaning, right?

Yes, that too means the same. It is possible, but not necessary, that there is a connection between her song and your dance. You may be dancing to the tune, or expressing in dance the sentiments of the words, but you could be performing completely independently.
